# Select Case problem

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have this code:

```
For each c as char in "Hello World"
 Select Case c
  Case "h"
   DoSomething()
  Case "e"
   DoSomething()
  End Select
Next
```

Why I cant write like this:

```
Case "h" Or "e"
 DoSomething()
```

It says *'Long' values cannot be converted to 'Char'*

How to accomplish this task?

Comment: Thats just not have Select statements work.

Comment: @Ash In C# maybe. They work that way in VB, Cobold just has the syntax slightly wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
Select Case c
  Case "h"
  Case "e"
    DoSomething()
End Select
```

or:

```
Select Case c
  Case "h","e"
    DoSomething()
End Select
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Case "h", "e"
   DoSomething()
```

if I remember my VB (which is dubious)

The error message *appears* to be due to it trying a *bitwise* "or" operation between the two strings, which seems pretty random.

Comment: Your solution is correct but the [Or](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06s37a7f.aspx) operation is not random: It "Performs a bitwise disjunction on two numeric expressions."

Comment: @Matt - I'm just confused why "h" or "e" is a `long` ;p

Comment: I guess the result of the Or is evaluating to a long (but I think this *shouldn't* compile)

Comment: @Matt Turn `Option Strict On` and it won't compile. Turn it on **now**, in your VB settings, so it's on for all new projects. @Marc it looks like the compiler is happy to emit code to coerce these strings to `Long` (although these specific strings will cause runtime errors) but it's not happy to coerce `(Long) Or (Long)` to `Char`. A person could go crazy here, let's all use `Option Strict On` instead :)

Answer (score 1):

```
For each c as char in "Hello World"
    Select Case c.ToString 'When putting certain objects VB will true/false result of if the string is empty(false) or has text(true).
        Case "h", "E"
          DoSomething()
        Case "e", "H"
          DoSomethingElse()
    End Select
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The case tries to match on *c*, but *c* is a char and *'h' or 'e'* is a boolean expression. But the cases must have the same type as in the select condition declared.
For solution see [Marek G.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278017/select-case-problem/6278046#6278046)

Comment: Yes, irrelevant, bitwise expression also doesn't match to char :-)